# qtree: missing { inserted

Tags: qtree

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
        \Tree [.A 
                    [.B [.D a] a [.E b]]    
                    [.C [.D c] b [.D c]] 
                    [.B [.D b]] 
              ]
\end{document}
```

Trying to compile this yields "missing {" error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put whitespaces before the inner right brackets

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
        \Tree [.A 
                    [.B [.D a ] a [.E b ]]    
                    [.C [.D c ] b [.D c ]] 
                    [.B [.D b ]]
              ]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? And is it an issue peculiar to qtree, or does the same kind of problem apply more generally?

Comment: @LarsH That's probably how the author decided to parse the input. I guess it looks for the next character and it sees `b]` if you don't put a whitespace. Regarding the generality, it depends on the convenience, with a guarantee of whitespace you don't need to check if the argument has any closing brace during the input parsing. But TikZ based ones are often much more flexible.